# scala compile-type check for valid filepath?

Tags: scala, type-level-computation

How do I create 'string type' that checks whether the file exists on some path at compile-time?
e.g)

```
val spaceshipModelPath: ResourceFilePath(from="appRoot/assets") = "appRoot/assets/spaceshipModel.obj"
```

or:

```
type ObjResourcePathType = ResourceFilePath["appRoot/assets", ".obj"]
val spaceshipModelPath: ObjResourcePathType = ...
```

Comment: this doesn't seem very useful - even if it does exist at compile time, can still disappear when the program runs.

Comment: @Dima one use case would be game-engine (copies file at compile-time).
The user *may* delete the file, but that's not what I'll have to care.

Comment: If you want to copy a file at compile time, just make that part of the build.

Comment: @Dima that won't protect me from accessing invalid asset paths, which would be a runtime error that could have been a compile-time error

Comment: It'll be a runtime error anyway if the file is removed after compilation finishes. Unit tests can be used to check the asset path validity.

Comment: @Dima that's what I mean by "the user *may* delete the files" above.

Comment: @Dima wait... are you worried about having my assets at projFolder/src/assets but after the build my assets will be at projFolder/target/assets (or somewhere else)? in that case, the path resolution is 'relative'

Comment: I am not worried about your assets at all :) Just saying that checking that they exist at compile time doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Dima it's just an extra-level of guarantee - I don't want to load non-existent model, and I want that to be checked at compile time. Also, I always have those model files during compilation stage, so why not?

Comment: Ok, if you say so ... This is normally done with unit tests. And rationally it makes no sense. But I don't know how to argue with "I want ..." :)

Comment: Scala (and functional programming in general) is all about invariants. If you got a program, that compiles one day, and does not compile the next without any changes to the code, that's not a good program.

Comment: @Dima I'm not looking at scala as only 'functional' language... it's a language that can extend its compiler features - for example, see http://getquill.io/

Comment: It's not "only" functional programming, but FP is its main feature.

Comment: @Dima it's not like I'd have to use 'main feature' 100% of the time... see the demo from http://getquill.io/, which obviously cannot be covered with '100%-only-fp'

Comment: I am not sure what that demo has to do with your question. Does that library make the same code sometimes compile and sometimes not?

Comment: @Dima it's basically connecting to a sql-DB during compile-time to provide compile-time checks & auto-completions. That's why I tagged this question "type-level computation"

Comment: So, if I am not connected to database, it won't compile? That library sucks.

Comment: @Dima well that's your definition of 'sucks' - others appreciate that library since it allows them to get autocompletion&compile-checks for databases done by some 3rd party guys